# Creating text string gets wrong output (postgresql)

Tags: string, postgresql, crosstab

I am trying to create a text string for later use in a semi dynamic crosstab function.

All is well as long as I not use the format "numeric(x,x)

```
SELECT concat('sign varchar,',(SELECT string_agg(col,',') 
FROM   (SELECT to_char(generate_series('2016-01-01','2016-01-15', interval '1 week'),'\"iyyy-iw\"  numeric(10,2)')col )cols))
```

The output is very strange. The letter "i" is replaced with a number.

```
sign varchar,"2015-53" numer5c(10,2),"2016-01" numer6c(10,2),"2016-02" numer6c(10,2)
```

How do I get a correct text string with "numeric(x,x)" as column format?

Sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/10313

TIA,

Comment: This seems to be related to the year in your series, where the i is used in '\"iyyy-iw\". These i's will be replaced somewhere.

Comment: I am not sure. Replacing the format with \"YYYY-MM-DD\" makes no difference. "http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/10331

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write `"numeric(10,2)"` instead of `numeric(10,2)` in your format string.

[The fine manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) says:

> Ordinary text is allowed in `to_char` templates and will be output literally. You can put a substring in double quotes to force it to be interpreted as literal text even if it contains pattern key words.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!